# How to add control to gates in Cirq?

Tags: programming, cirq

My question is very simple. I know there is a method to add a control to previously defined gates. I saw in the API of cirq that there is a command Controlled gate ([here](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/cirq.ControlledGate.html#cirq.ControlledGate)). I'm not understanding though how would this work. Suppose for example I want to add a control to an XPowGate from cirq. How would I write this in a program and how would I define the control qubit and the qubit over which I want to act?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `controlled_by` method on any Operation:

```
op = cirq.X(target_qubit).controlled_by(control_qubit)
```

You can also use `controlled` before specifying the target qubits:

```
op = cirq.X.controlled().on(control_qubit, target_qubit)
```

There are also built-in controlled operations such as `cirq.CNOT`, `cirq.CZ`, and `cirq.CSWAP`. The built-in operations are generally preferable because they have hand-tuned gate decompositions and simulation methods. The general `controlled_by` has to fall back to more general methods.

Note that the controlled versions of gates support things like raising to a power. The following three expressions produce equivalent operations:

```
(cirq.X(q)**0.5).controlled_by(c)

(cirq.X**0.5).on(q).controlled_by(c)

cirq.X(q).controlled_by(c)**0.5
```

Comment: Thank you! if I have to a two-qubit gate and want to add a control, then I would have to write:
 controlled_x = cirq.ControlledGate(cirq.TwoQubitGate)
return controlled_x.on(control_qubit, target_qubit1, target_qubit2)

right?

Comment: @Pam That's right.